# How to control recomputation order of helpers

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Why does the helper `calcFoo` rerun even though the element in the the array is not present anymore after you click on div? I guess because the `calcFoo`-helper depends on `fooRD` and gets rerun before the `foo`-helper gets rerun. Is there a way to control the recomputation order, so that `foo` is recomputed first and `calcFoo` does not need to rerun anymore (for elements that are already deleted)?

**foo.js**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.foo.onCreated(function() {
        this.fooRD = new ReactiveDict()
        this.fooRD.set('field', [1,2])
    })

    Template.foo.helpers({
        foo: function() {
            ti = Template.instance()
            return ti.fooRD.get('field')
        },
        calcFoo: function(v) {
            ti = Template.instance()

            // establish dependency
            ti.fooRD.get('field')
            console.log("run: " + v)
            return v * 2
        }
    })

    Template.foo.events({
        'click': function (e, t) {
            ti = Template.instance()
            field = ti.fooRD.get('field')
            field.pop()
            ti.fooRD.set('field', field)
        }
    })

}
```

**foo.html**

```
<body>
  {{> foo}}
</body>

<template name="foo">
    {{#each foo}}
        <div class="foo">{{calcFoo this}}</div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

My **workaround** so far (which does work in this simple case, but not in more complex scenarios):

```
calcFoo: function(v) {
    ti = Template.instance()

    field = ti.fooRD.get('field')
    if (field.indexOf(v) != -1)
        console.log("run: " + v)
        return v * 2
}
```

Comment: Unrelated tip: the `t` argument from your event functions basically *is* `Template.instance()` so you can use it directly to refer to your ReactiveDict: `field = t.fooRD.get('field')`

Comment: @BraveKenny i'm using Template.instance() for consistency reasons: t<=>Template.instance() only when used in the eventmap. inside helpers, there is no t.

Comment: So it is a thought-out decision then. No worries, I personally prefer simplicity over consistency, but it's purely a matter of taste indeed. :)

Comment: I think that **this** is already Template.instance() on your helper, so you can write directly this.ti.fooRD.get('field') . And on your event handler you should use t like @BraveKenny said.

Comment: @Ser `this.ti.fooRD` ? if you meant `this.fooRD`, it doen't work. `this` inside helpers refers to the arguments for the template `foo`.

Comment: Indeed, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

With this new helper, *calcFoo* is not anymore called :

```
Template.foo.helpers({
    hasFoo: function(v) {
        ti = Template.instance()
        return ti.fooRD.get('field').length > 0;
    }
})

<template name="foo">
  {{#if hasFoo}}
      {{#each foo}}
          <div class="foo">{{calcFoo this}}</div>
      {{/each}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: sry, I had to rephrase the question. it's not that the array has only one element (I thought this would simplify the problem).